# If 2 booleans are true

Tags: php, if-statement, boolean

I can't understand why the last debugbar message is showing. Strangely enough `$nest = 1`, not `true`.

```
$nest = true;
$showcosts = false;

Debugbar::info($nest);
Debugbar::info($showcosts);
Debugbar::info("x" . $nest . "x");
Debugbar::info("x" . $showcosts . "x");

Debugbar::info($nest == true);
Debugbar::info($showcosts);

if ($showcosts && $nest) {

    Debugbar::info("this should never show");

}
```

returns this:

```
true
false
x1x
xfalsex
true
false
this should never show
```

I'd like the last debugbar message not to show as only one of the conditions in the `if` statement is `true`.

I'm using Laravel 5.4 with PHP 7.

Comment: The string value of a boolean true is 1 which is why you get `x1x` when you concatenate strings. **However** the string value of a `false`should be the empty string and not the string `false`  which means you should also see a `xx` outputed (not `xfalsex`) . Make 100% sure that `$showcosts` is a boolean and not a string that contains the word `false`

Comment: Check [this code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8c2d19dcd1a1715ac1e2cd993cdf70b0be52d509) vs [this one](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dca3a9ceaba5a653da1ca69c90194fd9dfa9956e)

Comment: To complete the @apokryfos' comment (which seems to be the explanation to the exposed behaviour), the string `"false"` is `true` when it is [evaluated as boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

Comment: @apokryfos you're excatly right, $showcosts was actually a string coming from an AJAX request. Upvote for picking that up even though I had put $showcosts = false at the top.

Comment: I'm sure if $nest is `true` and `$showcosts` is false the if body will not run.

Comment: Sidenote: If you do `filter_var($showcosts,FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN)` it will convert the string false to a boolean false

Comment: Unnecessary downvote, this question shows effort and is clear to me. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment above:
The string value of a boolean `true` is `1` which is why you get `x1x` when you concatenate strings. However the string value of a false should be the empty string and not the string `false` which means you should also see a `xx` outputed (not `xfalsex`) .

Make 100% sure that $showcosts is a boolean and not a string that contains the word false because that behaviour is consistent with checking a `false` string.

In addition as @NinoŠkopac pointed out, the simple `if ($variable)` check will be true for any value of `$variable` which is considered "truthy". This includes non-null objects, non-empty arrays, non-zero numbers and non-empty strings as well as the boolean `true`. In this case the string `"false"` is a non-empty string and is therefore a "truthy" value.

If you're getting values from a request query string or post (e.g. via `$_POST` or `$_GET`) you must keep in mind that all values are strings.

For this purpose PHP has a set of filtering functions that aim to help with this. There's [`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) and [`filter_input`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) (and others, check the manual for more details).

You can use `filter_var` on any variable, for example in your case you could do:

```
$nest = filter_var($nest,FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
$showcosts = filter_var($showcosts ,FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
```

The [`FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN`](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) filter:

> Returns TRUE for "1", "true", "on" and "yes". Returns FALSE otherwise.

You can also use `filter_input` to filter input directly.

For example if you have an input entry `$_POST["nest"]` then you can do:

```
filter_input(INPUT_POST,"nest",FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
```

This will also save you from an `isset` check.